# Java Why local scope variables cannot be hidden but the global ones can?

Tags: java, scope

In Java, Why local scope variables cannot be hidden but the global ones can?
For instance:

```
public class Hello {
  static int x = 10; 
  public static void foo() {
    int x = 20; // Hides the global variable with the value of "20" within the  
     method foo. 
     }
  }
```

But this isn't possible:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void foo() {
      int x = 20; 
      int y = 1;
      if(x >= 20) {
       int y = 10; // Cannot hide this
     }
}
```

I understand that I cannot hide a variable that has a local scope in more inner local scope but the question is WHY this happens? Is it because of the way that Java is designed? Are there any other exceptions like that?

Comment: Scope is defined in jls, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

Answer (score 0):

When local and global variables have the same name, local variables will take precedence than global variables.

if you want the value of local variable to be printed then it can be done by using the this operator.'this' will not be added by compiler, we need to add it explicitly to specify the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's how Java is designed, and as you are free to name any new variable however you like, it's easy to find a name that doesn't collide. And there is no benefit in hiding away local variables - it would just take away the ability to access them. They still exist and occupy memory. For hiding field names with local variables or method parameters, there are *a few* useful cases (see below).

The way you wrote the examples, both cases will cause confusion to the reader: "What does `x` or `y` mean?" The local variable `x` in your method has nothing to do with the field. But you gave these two different things the same name. So I'd recommend to avoid the colliding names here.

But there are two common situations where developers usually introduce a local variable (or in this case a parameter) with the same name as an instance field:

- Constructors like `public Hello(int x) { this.x = x; }`
- Setters like `public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }`

Here it's the same value that is first held in the parameter `x` and later in the field `x`, so they are very related. And on the very same line you see both expressions, giving another hint that it's technically two different variables/fields.

Especially with the constructors I'd always vote for that naming scheme, as it makes clear just from seeing the constructors declaration `Hello(int x)` that it's the `x` field getting the constructor's argument.

Summary: There's a useful and widely accepted application of allowing the first "hiding" pattern, but I've never seen a situation calling for the second one.